# Settimeout Within The Same Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

I need your help.
When I run the iframe and the click code in the code below separately without setting settimeout, it works, but when I add settimeout to both, I get a "findo is not defined" error.

```
setTimeout(function () { 
var findo = $('<iframe>') 
.attr('src',"url link")
.attr('id', 'sevecen')
.attr('class', 'class_in_iframe')
.appendTo('.class');},5000);
setTimeout(function () {var selo = findo.contents().find(".class 
id").trigger("click");},8000);
```

Comment: Move the second timeout inside the first one, with a delay of 3000. That way, it will have access to the `findo` variable you created locally in the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @blex, you should put the second timeout inside the first one and adjust wait time.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var findo = $("<iframe>")
    .attr("src", "url link")
    .attr("id", "sevecen")
    .attr("class", "class_in_iframe")
    .appendTo(".class");

    setTimeout(function () {
        var selo = findo.contents().find(".class id").trigger("click");
      }, 3000);

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this only when document is loaded. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFunction();
</script>
```

In myFunction, run your logic without timeout and check.